# Problemas con la función @file_get_contents

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, funciones, peticiones

Estoy usando ouo.io.php la cual utiliza `@file_get_contents` obviamente en **localhost(xampp)** funciona perfectamente, pero cuando lo subo al sitio este me devuelve un `false` y también lo he probado sin el `@` pero no devuelve nada.

Esto es lo que quiero usar
https://github.com/parzibyte/ejemplo-acortadores-php/blob/master/ouo.io.php obviamente al devolverme false me da el mensaje de error que se ha especificado.

Obviamente que en mi caso lo hice de manera dinámica recibiendo la url definida por el usuario como parámetro, que se pasa a través de ajax. Como había mencionado anteriormente en **localhost** funciona muy bien y crea dicho link acortado y me devueleve dicho link.

PD: `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);` ya lo tiene activado desde el cpanel y lo he agregado al header.php

Espero haberme explicado bien y desde ya muchas gracias.

---

**MUESTRA DEL ERROR:**

El enlace que se desea pasar: "https://discord.com/channels/@me" (web)

`Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Enlace inesperado al acortar con ouo.io: in /home/vilocjmf/public_html/inc/libs/ouo_api.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /home/vilocjmf/public_html/inc/php/ajax/ajax.generador.php(48): createAcortador('https://discord...') #1 /home/vilocjmf/public_html/inc/php/ajax_files.php(49): include('/home/vilocjmf/...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/vilocjmf/public_html/inc/libs/ouo_api.php on line 13`

El mismo enlace en localhost me devuelve `Link acortado: https://fc.lc/LegionAnx4931`(con ouo y fc)

la línea 13 del archivo ouo_api.php es `$acortado = file_get_contents("http://ouo.io/api/". urlencode($ouoapi) . "?s=". urlencode($param_link));`

Comment: pd: ya he intentado usar curl, y me hace exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el mensaje de error que ves?

Comment: ¿Seguro que le estás pasando un archivo válido? ¿Comprobaste la URL y que el archivo realmente existe ahí y que el usuario tiene permisos para leerlo?

Comment: @Muc edite el topic, allí marque el error

Comment: @Miguel92 parece ser que está arrojando una excepción particular de la librería que estás usando... habría que debugearla internamente a ver qué puede estar pasando